# Is it possible to apply filters on SqlPackage?

Tags: sql-server, schema, sqlpackage

We develop a lot of modules separately. This means the Blog module has its own database in development. All objects of each module start with the module schema. So the `Posts` table inside the Blog module is named `blog.Posts`.

However, in production we deploy all modules to one target database.

For example, this means that in production I will have these objects:

```
blog.Posts
content.Pages
seo.Configurations
menu.Items
email.Templates
```

Now, I want to compare Blog module database with the production database. I'm using SqlPackage for this purpose.

The point is that SqlPackage creates a huge drop script, because it thinks that all other tables from other modules that exist in the production database should be dropped.

Is there a way to tell SqlPackage to only compare the objects of a given schema? Can I configure SqlPackage to only compare `blog` schema?

Comment: You can select 'blog' tables (one by one), but I don't know if you can select a single schema. Look at `TableData` property.

Comment: https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer

Answer (score 2):

Check out the DropObjectsNotInSource option to [Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-script?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15) actions in SqlPackage.exe:

> /p:   DropObjectsNotInSource=(BOOLEAN)
>
> Specifies whether objects that do not exist in the database snapshot
> (.dacpac) file will be dropped from the target database when you
> publish to a database. This value takes precedence over
> DropExtendedProperties.